How to set up a Raspberry Pi as a WiFi Access Point?
I want to use a raspberry Pi as a wireless access point using hostapd. I have setup everything that my mobile devices find the SSID, get connected and get an IP address, including DNS and router.
However, still I cannot get to the internet, or even my internal net. I followed this guide, skipping the steps about the DHCP server (I have PiHole on this device as well, and the DHCP is already set up; I do get an IP address on the mobile devices).
This is my /etc/hostapd.conf file:
country_code=NL
interface=wlan0
ssid=SSID
channel=9
auth_algs=1
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=PASSPHRASE
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP CCMP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP

I enabled packet forwarding:
pi@pihole2:~ $ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
1

and my iptables rules should also be fine:
sudo iptables -t nat -A  POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
sudo iptables -t nat -A  POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE

pi@pihole2:~ $ sudo iptables -t nat -L -v
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
  756 51429 MASQUERADE  all  --  any    eth0    anywhere             anywhere
    1   330 MASQUERADE  all  --  any    wlan0   anywhere             anywhere
pi@pihole2:~ $ sudo iptables -t filter -L -v
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

I have configured both eth0 and wlan0 with a fixed IP. When wlan0 does not have a fixed IP, the mobile device does not get an IP address.
My guess is that something goes wrong with routing, possibly the route back to the mobile devices. But I have no idea where to look or how to fix it.
How can I get the routing correct when using an rPi as a WiFi access point?

What do you have in iptables for -t filter? What's the entire MASQUERADE rule in -t nat – as shown by -L -v or even -S?

@grawity_u1686 I updated the questions with these commands. Nothing special if you ask me ....

Perhaps you already know, but you really, really, REALLY, do not want to use a pi as an wifi ap. It's wifi capabilities are just far too poor with just a single onboard constrained antenna.

Do the two networks have unique IP addresses? (You can't route between identical subnets.) Does tcpdump show any packets being forwarded from one interface to the other?

@grawity_u1686 Yes I found that out as well. I gave the mobile subnet another ip range and it worked. Next is to configure the dnsmasq in such a way that it sends out the correct IP range on the wlan interface, but that is managed by PiHole, so I cannot do that easily.

@BobGoddard I do this because I have a single (old) device that doesn't work on my new WiFi 6 Mesh network. And before I decided to buy a new adapter or laptop, I'd try this solution, where I already have the hardware.
